# Bluetooth connection to HC-05 paired but not connected (in Linux)

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu, hc-05

I have an Arduino Uno connected to an HC-05 Bluetooth sender/receiver chip. I am trying to create a Bluetooth connection between my Acer laptop running under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the HC-05 chip.

Ubuntu detects the HC-05 chip, as can be seen below.

```
phodor@ubuntu: hcitool scan
Scanning ...
    11:22:33:44:55:66   HC-05
```

I am able to create a pair between my laptop Bluetooth device and the HC-05 chip. However, I am unable to create a connection with that pair from the Ubuntu interface. The "Connection" button cannot be clicked on, as you can see on the figure below.

I tried creating a connection using the terminal, but after that the terminal still did not detect any connection.

```
phodor@ubuntu: sudo hcitool cc 11:22:33:44:55:66
[sudo] password for phodor: 
phodor@ubuntu: hcitool con
Connections:
```

I also checked that my computer Bluetooth device was working.

```
phodor@ubuntu: hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

Any idea why the connection cannot be created ? Any idea on how to do it using the Ubuntu interface or the terminal ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in the [Bluetooth connection to HC-05 paired but not connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721954/bluetooth-connection-to-hc-05-paired-but-not-connected/1350834#1350834)

Step;

1.Once you have paired the HC-05 as you've described, bind the device by entering;

```
sudo rfcomm bind 0 "MAC address" 1
```

2.To trigger the connection & display the data using minicom, run;

```
sudo minicom -D /dev/rfcomm0
```

You'll notice that port /dev/rfcomm0 will be available from the arduino IDE as well.

3.To exit minicom, press ctrl+A and then X.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this website for more information

http://wiki.micropython.org/official-accessories/Bluetooth-module-HC05

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon at Stack Exchange. The answer should at least summarize what we would find if we followed the link. Plus, the link might go down. Please expand your answer.